# How to give smooth animation to ImageView when it expands to screen size in android

Tags: android

I am creating a chatting app and when a image arrives in chat it looks like this.

[image]

Now I want to achieve WhatsApp like effect. I think on WhatsApp when you click the image it expands to whole screen with a smooth animation. I can add click Listener on the image but I don't know how to achieve that effect with smooth animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this effect pretty easily with a [SharedElementTransition](https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/start-activity). In short, you create a new activity that only displays the image and tell the framework which view from the first activity/fragment corresponds to the image in the new activity and the rest is done automatically.

In the new activity layout add a transition name to the ImageView. You'll have to load the image in this activity manually, so you have to pass the URL to the activity if you're loading from the network, or pass the bitmap in another way.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:transitionName="image"/>
```

When the image is clicked you start the activity and specify ImageView clicked and map it to the transitionName:

```
 // If you're in a fragment
val activity = requireActivity()

// imageView here corresponds to the image before it is animated
// "image" is transitionName in the new activity
val options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(activity, imageView, "image")
activity.startActivity(Intent(context, ImageActivity::class.java), options.toBundle())
```

Also, the style used for the activities must set `android:windowContentTransitions` to true:

```
<style name="...">
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
</style>
```